# Fixing the width of a div via CSS override in uBlock Origin

Tags: css, adblock

I'm trying to make the comments wider on Slashdot, especially on mobile (Firefox). There is a big gap on the left.

Example: https://tech.slashdot.org/story/21/08/12/2034218/google-launches-interactive-3d-periodic-table-to-teach-chemistry

(any Slashdot story will work)

The selector is `div#comments.a2commentwrap`. Examining it you can see that it has the property `margin-right: 320px;` and if you reduce it to 20px the big gap goes away.
I can't get the rule to work though. I have

```
slashdot.org##div#comments.a2commentwrap:style(margin-right: 20px; !important;)
```

but it has no effect. I tested `background-color: #333!important;` and that worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you terminated your style with `;` before `!important` flag

```
slashdot.org##div#comments.a2commentwrap:style(margin-right: 20px !important;)
```